# _variable - why that underscore at the beginning?

Tags: coding-style

Sometimes I see people writing variable names like this:

> int _variable;

IMO That's really ugly. What's that about?

Comment: There's no language-defined meaning - it's just a convention some people use to distinguish instance variables from local variables. Google is a nice source to start

Comment: It depends. Which programming language are you referring to?

Comment: I quite like the ugliness. It makes it clear you're working with the ugly internal "gears" of the class.

Comment: e.g. in Python one distiguishes public, _protected, and __private class members this way

Comment: @ArinChakraborty: It is more than a convention at least in C and C++. The specifications reserve symbols starting with underscore for extensions and implementation details of the standard library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say you want to make the difference between two types of variables (such as private and public) very visual, so that anyone could tell which one is which just by glancing at the name of the variable.

- You may go with `privatePrice` and `publicQuantity`. This is hardly usable and requires more typing, wastes more screen space, etc.
- You may use an abbreviation or a convention, such as `rPrice` and `uQuantity`. This looks like Hungarian notation, is misleading and is not easily discoverable. Putting just the first letter won't help neither: which one is private, `pPrice` or `pQuantity`?
- Finally, you can use a symbol. Which symbols can be used in most languages and are available on most keyboards?

  1. Letters,
  2. Digits (but some languages forbid starting a variable name by a digit,
  3. Underscore.

  Dashes, dots, commas and brackets usually have different purposes. Unicode symbols are supported in many languages, but are difficult to use when typing source code. Accented letters such as "à" are easy to type on my French layout keyboard, but may be much more difficult to enter on a Chinese or Russian keyboard.

  Looks like underscore becomes an obvious choice.

**About its ugliness...**

Ugly is subjective. Let's concentrate on more objective notions. Design and UX principles, for example, are somehow much more objective than the terms such as "pretty" or "ugly", so let's talk design/UX. What word do you notice in the following text?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec laoreet elit. Nullam egestas eros vel luctus bibendum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et _malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed nec leo sem. Maecenas vitae augue non odio lacinia ornare a eget dolor.

That's because the underscore prefix is visually distinctive. In the same way, underscore improves the readability of code by being visually distinctive as a prefix: if you search the source code for a private member, your eye will catch identifiers starting by "_", but much less the ones which simply contain an underscore:

```
private Price computePrice(Product product)
{
    Price result = calculator.ComputePrice(product, Path_Default);

    if (_ruleset.isEnabled)
    {
        result.applyRuleset(_ruleset);
    }

    return result;
}
```

By glancing at this piece of code, you easily notice both `_ruleset`, but don't visually recognize `Path_Default` as a potential match.

**About its benefits...**

While this improves readability, the usage of underscore character as a prefix is not always a good idea. Some standards and style guides, such as the official C# style guide, forbid using underscore as a prefix for private variables, in the same way as it is forbidden to use Hungarian notation. The reason for that is that:

- First, the cases where you need to know the visibility of a variable is pretty rare, and in those cases, the IDE helps you to find this information in less than three seconds.
- Second, all those notations add visual clutter. Since it is not essential, it should be removed.
- Third, it is not unusual to end up with code like this:

  ```
  public string _Title { get; set; }
  ```

  and the sole fact that such convention may lead to misleading code and easily avoidable bugs, while the IDE will never lie is a good reason to avoid such conventions.

This being said, other communities using other languages find underscore prefix useful enough to communicate information. They may take a risk for the underscore prefix to become misleading (if the variable changes from private to public or from public to private but is not renamed properly), the risk similar to one that each developer takes when he writes a comment which may not be updated by the successive maintainers of the piece of code.